# Getting rid of design-time ArgumentNullException warnings in VS2010-Silverlight5

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-5.0, design-time

I have a Silverlight form that performs exception-based data validation. I learned how to do this data validation the following way:

Set controls to be validated as follows:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnValidationError=True, Source={StaticResource docSan}, Path= metadati.paziente.residenza, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"/>
```

Make the target property work as follows

```
public new string residenza
    {
        get { return base.residenza; }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
            base.residenza = value;
        }
    }
```

Where the base class defines a non-validating property in an `INotifyPropertyChanged` way

Unfortunately VS2010 at design time warns me about the exception for each text box. This doesn't prevent the application from running (it works **fine**) but it's just annoying.

Somebody knows how to tell VS that it's OK if at design time no value is specified thus the code throws naturally?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, it is the `if ... throw` statement in the setter that causes the warnings in the designer?

I think you can use the `DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool` to prevent this line from running in design-time:

```
set
{
    if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
    }
    base.residenza = value;
}
```

Comment: Seems it doesn't work. When I open the XAML file I get all the errors in the bottom of the IDE, but if I hit F6 it compiles fine, errors disappear but warnings are shown on top of the editor and I can't click on designed controls. Maybe I understood why: the problem could lie in the **getter** part because the designer wants to set value to the textboxes starting from the data bound object which is obviously null. Maybe I should change the getter and return empty string at design time if value is null but it seems really too odd. Everyone uses data binding today without problems

Comment: Visual Studio says: Il valore non può essere null.
Nome parametro: Text
   in System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.set_Text(String value)
"Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Text"

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? I have not managed to reproduce the error myself yet, but I will give it a few more shots. Hopefully I can come up with a sufficient solution from these attempts.

Comment: Full code: https://marcus.zighinetto.org/svnroot/masterict/trunk/StrutturaSanitaria2/